# How do I get the length of the first line in a multi line string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multilinestring

I have a multiline string generated by a script that creates ASCII art from an image. It creates a line, then adds `\r` and keeps going. How do I get the length of the first line, or before it says `\r` without using regex? Preferably the code is fairly readable.

Comment: What's wrong with regex? I think they would be an appropriate solution.

Comment: Is there another solution? I'd rather not use regex just because I haven't learned it yet and I'd rather my program contain only stuff I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
first, _, _ = s.partition('\r')
k = len(first)
```

If you don't need the string, you can just use `index`:

```
k = s.index('\r')
```

This works because `s.index('\r')` contains the lowest index `k` for which `s[k] == '\r'` -- this means there are exactly `k` characters (`s[0]` through `s[k-1]`) on the first line, before the carriage return character.

Comment: I accepted this because having the whole string before is useful. I'm using PIL to find the size, in pixels, of a string. I'm using a monospaced font, so it shouldn't matter whether I find the size of the whole string or the size of one character times the length of the line, but I feel safer finding the length of the whole line.

Answer (score 5):

With `find` or `index`?

```
>>> 'abcfoo\rhahahahaha'.find('\r')
6
>>> 'abcfoo\rhahahahaha'.index('\r')
6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import string
string.split(yourString, '\r')
length = len(string[0])
```

So what we have here is straight forward. We take your string and we split it as soon as we get the /r tag. Then, since all strings terminated with /r are in an array we simply count the first captured string in the array and assign it to the var length.

Comment: Why don't you edit this, add a line that says `length = len(string[0])`? That would be a valid response and work well.

Comment: Well you got so many great answers already that by the time I came to edit it it had already been answered lol

Comment: @ScottJohnson You should edit your answer and add some description. With a description, your answer will be here for posterity and future users with the same issue as the OP's might find your answer useful and upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you need yet another solution..:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    t = f.read()
    l = t.splitlines()
    print(len(l[0]))
```

Comment: That's good, too, I like this solution. Upvoted, but not accepted.