# How to find the length of the first line of a string in a multi line string in R

Tags: r, string, string-length

I am working on the following problem in R

[ **Note:** I realize that there is an answer posted to a similar question which is

[How do I get the length of the first line in a multi line string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30428320/how-do-i-get-the-length-of-the-first-line-in-a-multi-line-string)

however *I am looking for a solution in R, not in python*. ]

Suppose I have a string on multiple lines such as the one below:

```
"The first line of the string,
the second line of the string
and finally the the third line of the string."
```

I would like to know the length of just the first line of the string which is:

```
> nchar("The first line of the string,")
[1] 29
```

However the string is really stored as

```
> "The first line of the string,
+ the second line of the string
+ and finally the the third line of the string"
[1] "The first line of the string,\nthe second line of the string\nand finally the the third line of the string"
```

So when I apply the `nchar` function to the entire string, I get

```
> my_string = "The first line of the string,
+ the second line of the string
+ and finally the the third line of the string"
> nchar(my_string)
[1] 104
```

which is not correct.

Is there a way I can get the number of characters on just the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub` to remove everything after `\n` and use then `nchar`.

```
nchar(sub("\n.*", "", my_string))
#[1] 29
```

or using `strsplit`

```
nchar(strsplit(my_string, "\n")[[1]][1])
#nchar(strsplit(my_string, "\n")[[c(1,1)]]) #Alternative
#[1] 29
```

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution:

```
nchar(strsplit(my_string, "\n")[[1]])
```

Maybe a better one exists.

Answer (score 1):

baseR  solution

```
nchar( gsub( "(^[^\n]*).*$", "\\1", my_string) )
```

takes the part from the start of the string, untill the first `\n` (=newline character)